# How to markdown syntax to NSAttributedString iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, markdown, nsattributedstring

Is there any easy way to convert `Markdown Syntax` to `NSAttributedString`?
  I had a look at a third-party libraries, but they don't work well with Swift and outdated to iOS 6, as well as Cocoa Pods install is still in beta and failed on install:

[Native Markdown Parsing on iOS](https://github.com/dreamwieber/AttributedMarkdown)

Although I need to present the Markdown String on the `ViewController`, I have a `CustomCollectionViewLayout` which I need to calculate the height of the string with a specific font and width, the Markdown string I download from the API gives a wrong height.
 
 This is a sample of the Markdown text:

This is what I am about to do and present to the user. My list of things are: Eating Today __ Shake __ * 150 ml milk * 150 ml water * 40 g nuts , Vanille * 1 sugar

Comment: "Don't seem to work": Meaning?

Comment: @Larme thanks for your comment, I updated my question - don't work well with Swift and outdated to iOS 6, as well as Cocoa Pods install is still in beta and failed on install. Couldn't add the library to work on my project.